# How to stay on the Current Page in JavaScript after refresh

Tags: javascript, java, html

guys!

I am working on a project with Java + Javascript and when I refresh the page instead of staying in my home page, it's redirecting to login page.

I'm new to this and want to know how can I stay on same page after refreshing.
I read some examples but it's not clear how to achieve this.

Example: if I'm in Settings page and press F5 or reloa, I wanna stay in Settings Page.

Comment: Hi Ktj, it will be near impossible to actually help you without seeing what code you are working on.

Comment: We need to see the JavaScript & Java code. Please elaborate more on your project as well.

Answer (score 0):

.preventDefault can be used on event listeners to avoid refreshing
The event listener can be anything that causes the refresh

Comment: `.preventDefault` might stop a refresh from occurring where an event's default behaviour is to refresh the page. However, that doesn't answer the question being asked, which is how to stay on the same page _after_ a refresh.

The question being asked is ambiguous as staying on the current page after refresh likely depends on the implementation of the web application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `location.reload();` would be used to refresh to the same URL, but your application logic might only allow access to particular URLs after going through certain other steps - e.g. logging in.

Without more information, your question will be almost impossible to answer.

You should try to figure out the steps that your application goes through during a bootstrap (i.e. start-up), as refreshing in a web app is effectively a restart of the JavaScript application.